# Acumatica - Add Pivot table to customization

Tags: acumatica

How to add an Pivot table to the customization, Shared filter and GI can be added but How to add a Pivot table definition as part of customization to avoid rework of creating pivot table again and again with each installation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the pivot table will come along with the generic inquiry that is associated with it (Click "View inquiry"). Add that generic inquiry under the "Generic inquiries" section of the customization project

Comment: I don't think this is correct, I've created a Generic Inquiry (GI), with a Pivot Table, when adding the GI to a customisation pacakge then publishing it to another tenant/site, the GI is created, but no sign of the Pivot Table. Using the .xml export/import on the GI also only brings across the GI, no Pivot Table.